# Unexpected dotted line when editing html on Eclipse 4.3.2 with PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I'm using Eclipse with PyDev for my Django project. Everything fine except when editing html, there dotted underline for each line of HTML.

How can I remove these dotted line?

This is my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happened to me as well, but in Java editor :)

It was probable loaded by one of Jeeeyul's themes, and can be changed in
Eclipse Preferences > General > Appearance > Jeeeyul's Themes
look in the Editor tab

screenshot
[image]